# How to find whether a point lies on a line which is in parametric form?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

> Does the point $(1,8,3)$ line on the line with parametric equation:
>   $$x = 5 + 2t$$
>   $$y = 2 + 6t$$
>   $$z = 1 + 3t$$

I know how to solve if they give me a equation of a plane and ask whether the line intersect the plane or not. If it intersect I can find where it intersect(the point of intersection). Can someone help me please!

Comment: Try to solve for $t$ the following system $$\begin{cases} 2t+5=1\\ 6t+2=8\\ 3t+1=3\end{cases}$$ If you find a solution $t_0$, then $(1,8,3)$ lies on that line. If you find none, it doesn't.

Comment: From 6t+ 2= 8, 6t= 6 and t= 1.  Setting t= 1 in the other equations, we get 2(1)+ 5= 7, not 1.  That is enough to see that the point is not on the line.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Putting the values of the $x,y$ and $z$ co-ordinates of the point $(1,8,3)$ in the parametric equation of the line, see if they yield the same value of $t$. If yes, then the point is on the line. Else not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether a given point $(x,y,z)$ belongs to this line, you are asking whether
\begin{align*}
x-5&=2t\\
y-2&=6t\\
z-1&=3t
\end{align*}
i.e., whether $(x-5,y-2,z-1)=(2,6,3)t$ for some $t\in\mathbb R$.

In the other words, you want to know whether the vector $(x-5,y-2,z-1)$ is a multiple of the vector $(2,6,3)$.

For $(x,y,z)=(1,8,3)$ you get $(x-5,y-2,z-1)=(-4,6,2)$. Is it a multiple of $(2,6,3)$?